# RegExp Issue in MySQL Statement

Tags: mysql, regex

I have the following RegExp in mySQL:

```
WHERE telephone NOT REGEXP'(^[+][0-9]+\ )?([0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4})(\ x[0-9]+$)?'
```

This is supposed to select all phone numbers that are not in the `+0 000-000-0000 x000` format. It works almost perfectly except I have one customer that entered in `000-000-0000</span>` into the telephone field and this expression does not find it. I know I have it set to accept an optional extension, but how do I make sure that optional extension is in the correct format?

Comment: What if you change `(\ x[0-9]+$)?` to `(\ x[0-9]+)?$` ?  You may also want to change `(^[+][0-9]+\ )?` to `^([+][0-9]+\ )?`

Comment: Cleanse your data of `</span>` (etc) _before_ storing into a table.

Comment: @rick LOL that's the whole reason I wrote the function. I to clean out all the crap people have put in and not allow anything like it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ending anchor to what you have:

```
^([+][0-9]+\ )?([0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4})(\ x[0-9]+)?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jT9yT3/1)